# Extract matching lines between two other patterns

Tags: c++, regex, perl, c++11

I am trying to use regexes in C++ to extracts lines that match a certain word—from within regions in a file bounded by two other patterns. I also want to print the line number of each match.

I am currently running a `perl` command using `popen`, but I would like to do it with C++:

```
perl -ne 'if ((/START/ .. /END/) && /test/) {print "line$.:$_"}' file
```

This command finds regions between `START` and `END` and then from those extracts lines containing the word `test`.

How do I do this with regexes in C++?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ ?

Comment: I have but I don't know how to get the line number.

Comment: In that case, add the C++ you do have so far into the question (or write now what you know how to do), it will make answering it much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [semantics of Perl’s `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) are subtle. The code below emulates both `..` and the `while (<>) { ... }` implied by the `-n` switch to `perl`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

// emulate Perl's .. operator
void flipflop(bool& inside, const std::regex& start, const std::regex& end, const std::string& str)
{
  if (!inside && std::regex_match(str, start))
    inside = true;
  else if (inside && std::regex_match(str, end))
    inside = false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // extra .* wrappers to use regex_match in order to work around
  // problems with regex_search in GNU libstdc++
  std::regex start(".*START.*"), end(".*END.*"), match(".*test.*");

  for (const auto& path : std::vector<std::string>(argv + 1, argv + argc)) {
    std::ifstream in(path);
    std::string str;
    bool inside = false;
    int line = 0;
    while (std::getline(in, str)) {
      ++line;
      flipflop(inside, start, end, str);
      if (inside && std::regex_match(str, match))
        std::cout << path << ':' << line << ": " << str << '\n';

      // Perl's .. becomes false AFTER the rhs goes false,
      // so keep this last to allow match to succeed on the
      // same line as end
      flipflop(inside, start, end, str);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

For example, consider the following input.

```
test ERROR 1
START
test
END
test ERROR 2
START
foo ERROR 3
bar ERROR 4
test 1
baz ERROR 5
END
test ERROR 6
START sldkfjsdflkjsdflk
test 2
END
lksdjfdslkfj
START
dslfkjs
sdflksj
test 3
END dslkfjdsf
```

Sample runs:

```
$ ./extract.exe file
file:3: test
file:9: test 1
file:14: test 2
file:20: test 3

$ ./extract.exe file file
file:3: test
file:9: test 1
file:14: test 2
file:20: test 3
file:3: test
file:9: test 1
file:14: test 2
file:20: test 3
```